# How to specify the DNS server in host command

Tags: linux, networking, dns, domain-name

I want to use linux `host` command to query all records (A, TXT, etc.) of a domain. I find this possible using `-a` option as in: `host -a google.com`

However, I need to specify my own DNS server by its IP. I could not find any way to specify the resolver or the name server. I find this in dig as in: `dig MX google.co.uk @ns1.google.com` where the string after `@` is the name server. But I did not find a way to query all records (TXT, A, etc.) in `dig`.

I prefer to use `host`. How can I specify the name server n `host` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use:

`host -a google.com my.dns.server.com`

host [-aCdlnrsTwv] [-c class] [-N ndots] [-R number] [-t type] [-W wait]
     [-m flag] [-4] [-6] {name} [server]

Comment: +1 though I'm not *entirely* sure this is completely portable; I have seen some pesky differences between different versions of the `host` command.

Comment: For example, Debian has two distinct packages [bind-host](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/bind9-host) (which is arguably the more popular, given how widespread BIND is) and [knot-host](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/knot-host) but I believe there are version differences within different versions of BIND, too.

Comment: I ma using ubuntu. It did not work with me. When I use `dig` with the name server (I use its IP), it works. So I am sure my name server is up and running. When I used your suggested command format, It get: `~$ host -a mywerver.com mydns1.com
Trying "myserver.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: For some reason the vm got into `aborted` state. After starting it again the command worked successfully.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I tried it myself on Ubuntu first to make sure it worked!